# quick sort using stack in c

Tags: c, algorithm, stack, quicksort

In a C assignment, I need to implement quick sort using a stack and without recursion.

This is the function header (arr is the array to be sorted, size is its size):

`void StackBasedQuickSort(int* arr, int size)`

Assume a working Stack struct, and the following working functions (which were given to us as part of the asignment and cannot be changed):

1. `CreateStack(int size)` - creates a stack of given size.
2. `QuicksortDataStructureLimit(int size)` - returns the stack's desired size, calculated by 2*ceil(log(size)).
3. `IsStackEmpty(Stack* stack)` - return TRUE if stack is empty, false otherwise.
4. `IsStackFull(Stack* stack)` - return TRUE if stack is full, false otherwise.
5. `IsValidSubArray(int p, int r, int size)` - return TRUE if (0 <= p < r < size), false otherwise
6. `MaybePushIndices(Stack* stack, int p, int r, int size)` - If a valid sub-array (see 5), pushes p and then r to the stack. Otherwise, does nothing.
7. `Pop(Stack* stack)` - pops an integer from the stack.
8. `SwapIndices(int* arr, int p, int q)` - Swaps 2 elements in an array.

I've also implemented a Partition function, which I'm pretty sure works:

```
int Partition(int* arr, int p, int r) {
    int pivot = arr[r];
    int q = p;
    int j;

    for (j = p; j < r; j++) {
        if (arr[j] < pivot) {
            SwapIndices(arr, q, j);
            q++;
        }
    }
    SwapIndices(arr, q, r);

    return q;
}
```

I've managed to implement the quick sort well using 2 different ways:

First way:

```
void StackBasedQuickSort(int* arr, int size) {

    Stack* stack = CreateStack(QuicksortDataStructureLimit(size));

    MaybePushIndices(stack, 0, size - 1, size);
    while (!IsStackEmpty(stack)) {
        q = Pop(stack);
        p = Pop(stack);
        r = Partition(arr, p, q);
        if (IsStackFull(stack)) // for debugging
            printf("Stack is full(1st attempt)\n");
        MaybePushIndices(stack, p, r - 1, size);
        if (IsStackFull(stack)) // for debugging
            printf("Stack is full(2nd attempt)\n");
        MaybePushIndices(stack, r + 1, q, size);
    }

    FreeStack(stack);

}
```

And the second way:

```
void StackBasedQuickSort(int* arr, int size) {

    Stack* stack = CreateStack(QuicksortDataStructureLimit(size));

    p = 0;
    r = size - 1;
    if (!(IsValidSubArray(p, r, size))) return;
    do{
        while (IsValidSubArray(p, r, size)) {
            q = Partition(arr, p, r);
            PrintStackQuickSortState(stack, arr, p, q, r, size);
            if (IsStackFull(stack) && IsValidSubArray(q + 1, r, size))  // for debugging
                printf("STACK FULL!\n");
            MaybePushIndices(stack, q + 1, r, size);
            r = q - 1;
        }
        if (!(IsStackEmpty(stack))) {
            r = Pop(stack);
            p = Pop(stack);
        }
        else
            break;
    } while (IsValidSubArray(p, r, size));

    FreeStack(stack);

}
```

Now, here's my problem:
Both ways work with a bigger stack, but both ways don't work with the given stack size, which is part of the assignment and cannot be changed (i.e. the first way gives "Stack is full(2nd attempt)" warnings, and the second way gives "STACK FULL!" warnings, with the sort not working when warnings are given but working when warnings are not given).

Also, please take into account that I can only change the implementation of the Partition and StackBasedQuickSort functions.

Is there a way to implement this stack-based quick sort in a way that doesn't need more than a 2*ceil(log(size)) -sized stack?

Thanks!

EDIT:
In order to save more space on the stack, I've implemented an algorithm that pushes the indices of the smaller section to the stack and iteratively runs on the bigger part, but I am still using too much space on the stack (i.e. I get a "STACK FULL!" output, but the algorithm works well when I don't).

New code:

```
Stack* stack = CreateStack(QuicksortDataStructureLimit(size));
int p = -1, q = -1, r = -1;

p = 0;
r = size - 1;
if (!(IsValidSubArray(p, r, size))) 
    return;
else 
    q = Partition(arr, p, r);
while (1){ // will break when stack is empty
    while (IsValidSubArray(p, q - 1, size) || IsValidSubArray(q + 1, r, size)){
        if (q - 1 - p > r - q - 1){ // left > right (push right, iterate left)
            if (IsValidSubArray(q + 1, r, size) && IsStackFull(stack))
                printf("STACK FULL!\n");
            MaybePushIndices(stack, q + 1, r, size);
            r = q - 1;
            q = Partition(arr, p, r);
        }
        else{ // right >= left (push left, iterate right)
            if (IsValidSubArray(p, q - 1, size) && IsStackFull(stack))
                printf("STACK FULL!\n");
            MaybePushIndices(stack, p, q - 1, size);
            p = q + 1;
            q = Partition(arr, p, r);
        }
    }
    if (!(IsStackEmpty(stack))){
        r = Pop(stack);
        p = Pop(stack);
        if (IsValidSubArray(p, r, size))
            q = Partition(arr, p, r);
        PrintStackQuickSortState(stack, arr, p, q, r, size);
    }
    else
        break;
}

FreeStack(stack);`
```

Can anyone advice on making this work?

Comment: The trick is tail recursion. Tail recursion can be transformed into iteration, without need of stack. Quick sort makes two recursive calls each time. So the trick is, transform one into tail recursion and then into iteration, so you need to push only one onto stack.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
That's exactly what I did the second time, yet the stack is still too small.

Comment: OK, Now I see that. So now you put always the "second" (uneven;D) half on stack, and process the "first" one iteratively. So another trick is, as those subarrays may be uneven in size, to process the bigger part iteratively and use stack for smaller one. That way you reduce usage of stack.

Comment: Small clarification please: in point 6. you refer to `p` and `q` but there is no `q`.

Comment: Thank el pescado, I will try that as well.

grek, thanks for the comment, I've edited the original post.

Comment: I've tried implementing an algorithm that pushes the smaller part to the stack and iteratively runs on the bigger part, and I still can't get the code to work with the given stack size.
See edited post for new version of my code.

Comment: @Gil - as answered by greybeard - you want fewer indices on the stack, so push the larger part indices to handle the larger part later, and loop to handle the smaller part first.

Answer (score 1):

`In order to save more space on the stack, I've implemented an algorithm that pushes the indices of the smaller section to the stack and iteratively runs on the bigger part`

Enterprising.
This ensures index pairs stay in the stack as long as possible.

Having them stay as short as possible would be an improvement:

Handle the *smaller* part first.

Answer (score 0):

To Implement QuickSort using stack in C Language.

We can follow below steps and approach:

The implementation of QuickSort uses a stack to keep track of the partitions that need to be sorted.

> - Initialize a stack of pairs, stack, to store left and right
>   endpoints.
> - Push the left and right endpoints of the entire array onto the stack. While the stack is not empty:
> - Pop the two elements from the stack as left and right.
> - Choose a pivot as the element at index (left + right) / 2.
> - Partition the subarray arr[left..right] around the pivot using the standard "partition" algorithm.
> - If there are partitions on the left or right of the pivot that need to be sorted:
>
>   - Push their left and right endpoints onto the stack.
> - If not, move on to the next partition on the stack. Once the stack is empty, the array is sorted.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STACK_SIZE 100
    
void quick_sort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
    stack[++top] = left;
    stack[++top] = right;

    while (top >= 0) {
        right = stack[top--];
        left = stack[top--];

        int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];
        int i = left, j = right;

        while (i <= j) {
            while (arr[i] < pivot) i++;
            while (arr[j] > pivot) j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                i++; j--;
            }
        }

        if (left < j) {
            stack[++top] = left;
            stack[++top] = j;
        }
        if (i < right) {
            stack[++top] = i;
            stack[++top] = right;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 3, 7, 1, 2, 8, 4, 5 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    quick_sort(arr, 0, n - 1);

    printf("Sorted array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was bumped by a bot. As answered by greybeard, push indices for larger partition, loop on smaller. Working code that includes the 8 functions mentioned in the question (these were created from scratch based on the descriptions of the 8 functions).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _Stack
{
int indx;                               /* index */
int size;                               /* size */
int data[];                             /* data (flexible array member) */
}Stack;

static Stack * CreateStack(int size)
{
Stack * stack = (Stack *)malloc((2+size)*sizeof(int));
    stack->indx = 0;
    stack->size = size;
    return stack;
}

static int QuicksortDataStructureLimit(int size)
{
int log = 1;
int pwr = 2;
    while(pwr < size){
        log++;
        pwr *= 2;
    }
    return log*2;
}

static int IsStackEmpty(Stack* stack)
{
    return stack->indx == 0;
}

static int IsStackFull(Stack* stack)
{
    return stack->indx >= stack->size;
}

static int IsValidSubArray(int p, int r, int size)
{
    return((0 <= p) && (p < r) && (r < size));
}

static void MaybePushIndices(Stack* stack, int p, int r, int size)
{
    if(! IsValidSubArray(p, r, size))
        return;
    stack->data[stack->indx++] = p;
    stack->data[stack->indx++] = r;
}

static int Pop(Stack* stack)
{
    return stack->data[--stack->indx];
}

static void SwapIndices(int* arr, int p, int q)
{
int t;
    t      = arr[p];
    arr[p] = arr[q];
    arr[q] = t;
}

static int Partition(int* arr, int p, int r) {
    int pivot = arr[r];
    int q = p;
    int j;

    for (j = p; j < r; j++) {
        if (arr[j] < pivot) {
            SwapIndices(arr, q, j);
            q++;
        }
    }
    SwapIndices(arr, q, r);
    return q;
}

static void StackBasedQuickSort(int* arr, int size)
{
Stack* stack;
int p, q, r;

    p = 0;
    r = size - 1;
    if (!(IsValidSubArray(p, r, size))) return;
    stack = CreateStack(QuicksortDataStructureLimit(size));
    MaybePushIndices(stack, p, r, size);
    while(! IsStackEmpty(stack))
    {
        r = Pop(stack);
        p = Pop(stack);
        while(IsValidSubArray(p, r, size))
        {
#if 0
            if(IsStackFull(stack)){     /* debug check */
                printf("stack full \n");
                free(stack);
                return;
            }
#endif
            q = Partition(arr, p, r);
            if(q - p > r - q){          /* push larger, loop on smaller */
                MaybePushIndices(stack, p, q-1, size);
                p = q + 1;
            } else {
                MaybePushIndices(stack, q+1, r, size);
                r = q - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    free(stack);
}

int Rnd32()
{
static unsigned int r = 0;
    r = r*1664525 + 1013904223;
    return (int)r;
}

#define SIZE (1024)
int main()
{
int *arr = malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));
int i;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        arr[i] = Rnd32();
    StackBasedQuickSort(arr, SIZE);
    for(i = 1; i < SIZE; i++){
        if(arr[i] < arr[i-1])
            break;
    }
    if(i == SIZE)
        printf("passed\n");
    else
        printf("failed\n");
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Hoare partition:

```
static int Partition(int* arr, int p, int r) {
    int pivot = arr[(p+r)/2];
    int i = p-1;
    int j = r+1;
    while(1){
        while(arr[++i] < pivot);
        while(arr[--j] > pivot);
        if(i >= j) return j;
        SwapIndices(arr, i, j);
    }
}

static void StackBasedQuickSort(int* arr, int size)
{
Stack* stack;
int p, q, r;

    p = 0;
    r = size - 1;
    if (!(IsValidSubArray(p, r, size))) return;
    stack = CreateStack(QuicksortDataStructureLimit(size));
    MaybePushIndices(stack, p, r, size);
    while(! IsStackEmpty(stack))
    {
        r = Pop(stack);
        p = Pop(stack);
        while(IsValidSubArray(p, r, size))
        {
#if 0
            if(IsStackFull(stack)){     /* debug check */
                printf("stack full \n");
                free(stack);
                return;
            }
#endif
            q = Partition(arr, p, r);
            if(q - p >= r - q){         /* push larger, loop on smaller */
                MaybePushIndices(stack, p, q, size);
                p = q+1;
            } else {
                MaybePushIndices(stack, q+1, r, size);
                r = q;
            }
        }
    }
    free(stack);
}
```